# Is there any way to break and restart for loop if a condition is true?

Tags: java

I want the last loop to stop and restart at the same time if sum is superior to Tamis.PoidsInitial?
I mean delete all entered data and restart only the loop and not all code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double sum = 0;
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.###");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Tamis[] listeDesTamis = new Tamis[16];
    System.out.println("Entrer SVP votre poids initial");
    Tamis.setPoidsInitial(input.nextDouble());
    System.out.println("Entrer SVP le tamis avec la taille la plus grande en mm");
    double maille = input.nextDouble();
    for (int i = 0; i < listeDesTamis.length; i++) {
        listeDesTamis[i] = new Tamis(maille);
        maille /= 1.2589;
    }
    for (Tamis e : listeDesTamis) {
        System.out.println("Entrer le refus pour le tamis "
                df.format(e.getTaille()) + " mm en grammes");
        e.setRefus(input.nextDouble());
        sum += e.getRefus();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please format your code properly and reduce the number of blank lines.

Comment: Add the loop to a method that returns true if the loop was completed and false if it wasn't (use `return false` instead of break) and then call the method in a loop until it returns true

Answer (score 1):

I think you're trying to do something like:

```
do {
    for (Tamis e : listeDesTamis) {
        System.out.println("Entrer le refus pour le tamis "
                df.format(e.getTaille()) + " mm en grammes");
        e.setRefus(input.nextDouble());
        sum += e.getRefus();
        if (sum > Tamis.getPoidsInitial()) {
            System.out.println("Too much!! Start again.")
            break;
        }
    }
} while (sum > Tamis.getPoidsInitial());

 System.out.println("Phew. We have sufficient.")
```

I have duplicated a small expression there in order to keep it uncomplicated and give a nice postcondion.

I would tend to avoid boolean flags and `continue` where practical.

You could do it in one loop using an `Iterator` that you reassign or reset (`ListIterator`) if you exceed the limit, but that's a bit of a mess too.

(I hope Tamis isn't something rude.")

Answer (score 0):

Put the loop you want to restart inside another loop:

```
outer: do {
  for (...) {
    if (whatever condition) continue outer;
  }
} while (false);
```

If the for loop completes without the condition being true, the outer loop doesn't execute again.

Answer (score 0):

Logic along the lines of the below should help get you going in the right direction;

```
while(booleanVariable == true){

    //do some logic here

    if(someConditionIsMet){
       booleanVariable == false;
       break;
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

set the iteraror from the for loop (in your example i) to 0 and then the for loop will start over